# React router taking 'new' as id

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using [ReactRouter](https://reactrouter.com/core/guides/quick-start) in my react project. I am using routing like this:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/users/new">
      <CreateUser />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/users/:userId">
      <Profile />
    </Route>
  <Switch>
```

Here I am facing problem when I am trying to load `localhost:3000/users/new` the `<Profile />` component load as well as `<CreateUser />` component and show error 'new' is not a valid userId. Without changing the path how can I solve this?

Comment: You can check here https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order of routes. Route with `users/new` should come first, followed by `users/:userID`. In your case router interprets `users/new` as `users/:userID`

Comment: Then probably there is another issue. If you would provide more code, that could help people to find it.